# String casting error in a Doubly Linked list

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I asked a question about this code yesterday which helped me overcome that issue, however now I am having other issues. I am taking a doubly linked list and writing the add, remove, reset, etc. functions for it. I have what should work for everything with the exception of the remove (which I am not quite sure of the error there), but the main issue is an error I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to support.DLLNode
at Double.add(Double.java:155)
at Double.main(Double.java:172)
```

I am looking for suggestions as to what I should do to fix this error and fix the last part of the remove method. Here is the code:

```
import ch06.lists.*;
import support.*;



public class Double<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ListInterface<T> {

protected DLLNode<T> front; //Front of list
protected DLLNode<T> rear; //Rear of list
protected DLLNode<T> curPosition; //Current spot for iteration
protected int numElements; //Number of elements in list

public Double() {
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    curPosition = null;
    numElements = 0;
}

protected DLLNode<T> find(T target) {
    //While the list is not empty and the target is not equal to the current element
    //curr will move down the list. If curr becomes null then return null.
    //If it finds the element, return it.
    DLLNode<T> curr;
    curr = front;
    T currInfo = curr.getInfo();
    while(curr != null && currInfo.compareTo(target) != 0) {    
        curr = (DLLNode<T>)curr.getLink();      
    }
    if (curr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return curr;
    }           
}

public int size() { 
    //Return number of elements in the list 
    return numElements;     
}

public boolean contains(T element) {
    //Does the list contain the given element?
    //Return true if so, false otherwise.
    if (find(element) == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean remove(T element) {
    //While the list is not empty, curr will move down. If the element can not
    //be found, then return false. Else remove the element.
    DLLNode<T> curr;
    curr = front;

    while(curr != null) {   
        curr = (DLLNode<T>)curr.getLink();      
    }
    if (find(element) == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (curr == null) {
            curr = curr.getBack();
            curr = rear;
        }
        else if (curr == front) {
            curr = (DLLNode<T>)curr.getLink();
            curr = front;
        }
        else if (curr == rear) {
            curr = curr.getBack();
            curr = rear;
        }
        else {
            //curr.getLink().setBack(curr.getBack());
            //curr.getBack().setLink(curr.getLink());

        }
    return true;
    }
}   

public T get(T element) {
    //Return the info of the find method.
    if (find(element) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return find(element).getInfo();
    }

}

public String toString() {
    DLLNode<T> curr;
    curr = front;
    String ans = "";
    while (curr != null) {
        ans = ans + " " + curr.getInfo();
        curr = (DLLNode<T>)curr.getLink();
    }
    return ans;
}

public void reset() {
    //Reset the iteration back to front
    curPosition = front;        
}

public T getNext() {
    //Return the info of the next element in the list
    DLLNode<T> curr;
    curr = front;
    //while (curr != null) {
        //curr = (DLLNode<T>)curr.getLink();
    //}
    if ((DLLNode<T>)curr.getLink() == null) {
        return null;
    }   
    else {
        curr = (DLLNode<T>)curr.getLink();
        return curr.getInfo();
    }       
}

public void resetBack() {

}

public T getPrevious() {
    //Return the previous element in the list
    DLLNode<T> curr;
    curr = front;
    if ((DLLNode<T>)curr.getLink() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if((DLLNode<T>)curr.getBack() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        curr = curr.getBack();
        return curr.getInfo();
    }
}

public void add(T element) {
    //PreCondition: Assume the element is NOT already in the list
    //AND that the list is not full!
    DLLNode<T> curr;                
    DLLNode<T>  newNode = (DLLNode<T>) element;
    curr = front;
    if (curr == null) {
        front = (DLLNode<T>)element;
    }
    else {
        newNode.setBack(curr.getBack());
        newNode.setLink(curr);
        curr.getBack().setLink(newNode);
        curr.setBack(newNode);
        curr = newNode;
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args){

    Double<String> d = new Double<String>();
    d.add("Hello");
    d.add("Arthur");
    d.add("Goodbye");
    d.add("Zoo");
    d.add("Computer Science");
    d.add("Mathematics");
    d.add("Testing");

    System.out.println(d);


}  

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the whell? You should use the standard Java APIs instead.

Comment: Reinventing wheels is a common path to learning.

Comment: As @DonRoby stated, it is a great way to learn. And seeming as I am currently in the Java level of my Computer Science Major, its a great way to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is in the `add(T element)` method where you are casting:

`DLLNode<T>  newNode = (DLLNode<T>) element;`

But you pass the `element` as a `String` not a `DLLNode`. See your main method: `d.add("Hello");`

When adding, do something like: `DLLNode newNode = new DLLNode(element);`

You can take a look at java [LinkedList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java) source (for inspiration on implementation and the right usage of generics for your problem).

Comment: Okay, I can do that and get it to compile. Still returns the same error when attempting to run it. However if I change it to newNode = front;   I get just an empty string printed out. front = newNode still returns the same error

Comment: @JefferyTylerStewart It's very difficult for anyone to guide you step by step remotely until you get it done especially when the 200 lines code you posted is not compiling. Beside this, SO is in question-answer format. People just answered your question and indicated the problem from the question. A better site for what you want might be: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It compiled before, just returned said error when I ran it. But I do appreciate the comments and that site.

Comment: I meant: is not compiling on the machine of who might want to help you.

Comment: Ah okay. Yea that is quite difficult since most of the imports are coming from a bookFiles folder retrieved from a book's manufacturer's site that I am using to learn. But like I said, I do appreciate it. Your suggestion did help me move along.

Answer (score 0):

In your `add(T element)` method, you have a line

```
DLLNode<T>  newNode = (DLLNode<T>) element;
```

This cast does not work.

Clearly you wish to create a new node containing the element as info to add to your list here.

What you want is probably

```
DLLNode<T>  newNode = new DLLNode<T>();
newNode.setInfo(element);
```

(I'm assuming your `DLLNode` has this setter, as it has other setters.)

Comment: Double.java:152: error: constructor DLLNode in class DLLNode<T#2>       cannot be applied to given types;
  DLLNode<T> newNode = new DLLNode<T>();

------------Is what I receive when attempting that, and no, there is no such thing as a setInfo()

Comment: To deal with this further, I think we'd have to see the code for your DLLNode class.